# Exception in Quicksort Implementation of CLRS' Algorithm

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying out an implementation of QuickSort given in CLRS but it gives an Array Index out of bounds exception.The following are the methods.
Array was called from main with an array of 10 elements generated randomly.

```
public static String quicky(int[] array, int a, int b)
    {
        int q ;
        if(a<b)
        {
            q = partition(array,a,b) ;     //Exception
            System.out.println(q);
            quicky(array,a,q-1) ;
            quicky(array,q+1,b) ;     //Exception
        }    
        return Arrays.toString(array) ;
    } 
    public static int partition(int[] arr, int p, int r)
    {
        int temp ; 
        int x = arr[r] ;
        int i = p-1 ;
        for(int j=0 ; j<arr.length-1 ; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]<=x)
            {
                i++ ;
                temp = arr[i] ;
                arr[i] = arr[j] ;
                arr[j] = temp ;
            }    
        }
        temp = arr[i+1] ;              //Exception
        arr[i+1] = arr[x] ;
        arr[x] = temp ;
        return i+1 ;
    }
```

Comment: Please, comment beside the line you are getting exception like - `//exception`

Comment: Please stacktrace to question

Answer (score 0):

There were a few bugs in the code like off-by-ones and the wrong variables being used. Try:

```
public static String quicky(int[] array, int a, int b)
{
    int q ;
    if(a<b)
    {
        q = partition(array,a,b) ;
        quicky(array,a,q-1) ;
        quicky(array,q+1,b) ;     
    }    
    return Arrays.toString(array) ;
}

public static int partition(int[] arr, int p, int r)
{
    int temp ; 
    int x = arr[r] ;
    int i = p-1 ;
    for(int j=p ; j<=r-1 ; j++)
    {
        if(arr[j]<=x)
        {
            i++ ;
            temp = arr[i] ;
            arr[i] = arr[j] ;
            arr[j] = temp ;
        }    
    }
    temp = arr[i+1] ; 
    arr[i+1] = arr[r] ;
    arr[r] = temp ;
    return i+1;
}
```

Comment: This does solve the question a bit. The entire array isn't getting sorted though. Thanks anyways, I am sure I can now build over this.